# How to build an Android app (client side and server side) with the help of Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Good day everyone.
I am desperately in need of rich and straightforward answers. So, Please For Your Help.
I am building for the first time an android application to access diverse files on mobile devices. My idea is to have a client app on the device and an application server on Google App Engine that search effectively the files and answers the client app. I also consider having a data store in Google cloud to store all the files. This might not really make sense because I am not very sure of the way Google cloud works but, may be you can help me with a better proposal to make sense out of it all. Another point is how to make the client app accessible to multiple users in order for them to also use the system and access the files. Is it by publishing the client app in Google play?
Thanks in advance for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow, but here are some pointers to relevant features:

- The Google API client for Android has everything you need to make authenticated requests to your Cloud services, including your custom app on App Engine: https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html
- You can use Google Cloud Endpoints to create the server API for your mobile clients: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/
- Depending on how you want to structure your app, it might be useful to interact with Cloud Storage directly, such as for uploading and downloading the files: https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/ https://developers.google.com/storage/
- Here's an introduction to publishing your Android app to the Google Play store: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html

Good luck!